# Mongoid executes one query per document field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm looking at the logs of an API request and I'm seeing several mongodb queries for the same item in the same collection:

```
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"concrete_bounties", "filter"=>{"bounty_group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5789a7fb92ba744522000069'), "is_initiator"=>true}, "limit"=>-1, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001166488s
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"concrete_bounties", "filter"=>{"bounty_group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5789a7fb92ba744522000069'), "is_initiator"=>true}, "limit"=>-1, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001271851s
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"concrete_bounties", "filter"=>{"bounty_group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5789a7fb92ba744522000069'), "is_initiator"=>true}, "limit"=>-1, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.0011178170000000001s
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"concrete_bounties", "filter"=>{"bounty_group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5789a7fb92ba744522000069'), "is_initiator"=>true}, "limit"=>-1, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001772669s
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"concrete_bounties", "filter"=>{"bounty_group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5789a7fb92ba744522000069'), "is_initiator"=>true}, "limit"=>-1, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.003027585s
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"fans", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('577d410292ba742b6b00335f')}, "limit"=>-1}
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000534343s
MONGODB | 127.0.0.1:27017 | opera_bounties_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"concrete_bounties", "filter"=>{"bounty_group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5789a7fb92ba744522000069')}, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}
```

`rack-mini-profiler` also tells me that I'm running a query for every field:

```
app/models/bounty_group.rb:91:in `initiator_bounty'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/_show.jbuilder:12:in `_app_views_api_bounty_groups__show_jbuilder___4003829608010900196_70143133442560'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:11:in `block (4 levels) in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:10:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:9:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:8:in `block in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:6:in `_app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'

{:command_name=>"find", :database_name=>"opera_bounties_development", :command=>{"find"=>"concrete_bounties", "filter"=>{"bounty_group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('578d905e92ba741e17000036'), "is_initiator"=>true}, "limit"=>-1, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}, :request_id=>nil}   

app/models/bounty_group.rb:91:in `initiator_bounty'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/_show.jbuilder:13:in `_app_views_api_bounty_groups__show_jbuilder___4003829608010900196_70143133442560'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:11:in `block (4 levels) in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:10:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:9:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:8:in `block in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:6:in `_app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'

{:command_name=>"find", :database_name=>"opera_bounties_development", :command=>{"find"=>"concrete_bounties", "filter"=>{"bounty_group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('578d905e92ba741e17000036'), "is_initiator"=>true}, "limit"=>-1, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}, :request_id=>nil}      

app/models/bounty_group.rb:91:in `initiator_bounty'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/_show.jbuilder:14:in `_app_views_api_bounty_groups__show_jbuilder___4003829608010900196_70143133442560'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:11:in `block (4 levels) in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:10:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:9:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:8:in `block in _app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'
app/views/api/bounty_groups/index.jbuilder:6:in `_app_views_api_bounty_groups_index_jbuilder__3982354297104172694_70143133979520'

{:command_name=>"find", :database_name=>"opera_bounties_development", :command=>{"find"=>"concrete_bounties", "filter"=>{"bounty_group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('578d905e92ba741e17000036'), "is_initiator"=>true}, "limit"=>-1, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}}, :request_id=>nil}
```

Am I misinterpreting the data, or is it actually happening? If it's an actual performance issue, how do I fix it? I thought I'm using jbuilder correctly in my views, such as the following:

```
json.id                      bounty_group.id.to_s
json.challenge               bounty_group.action
json.status                  bounty_group.state
json.fail_condition          bounty_group.fail_condition
json.total_amount            bounty_group.amount
```